# Data Source in Custom Controls vs. in XPages and BeforeRenderResponse Event

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have some strange behavior, lets take a look at the following examples:

### The first example without any problems:

*XPage (with an included datasource)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="docData" 
            formName="frmPrototype" 
            action="openDocument"
            documentId="3DEF64BFAD6E1F32C12580B8003CB18F">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xc:ccModule></xc:ccModule>

</xp:view>
```

*Custom Control "ccModule"*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xc:ccSubModule></xc:ccSubModule>

</xp:view>
```

*Custom Control "ccSubModule"*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("beforePageLoad");
print(docData.getDocument().getUniversalID());
print(docData.getItemValueString("Subject"));}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("beforeRenderResponse");
print(docData.getDocument().getUniversalID());
print(docData.getItemValueString("Subject"));}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>

</xp:view>
```

**Output as expected:**

[image]

### Now the slightly different second example:

In this example the data source was moved to the `ccModule` custom control.

*XPage*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xc:ccModule></xc:ccModule>

</xp:view>
```

*Custom Control "ccModule" (with an included datasource)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="docData" 
            formName="frmPrototype" 
            action="openDocument"
            documentId="3DEF64BFAD6E1F32C12580B8003CB18F">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xc:ccSubModule></xc:ccSubModule>

</xp:view>
```

*Custom Control "ccSubModule"*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("beforePageLoad");
print(docData.getDocument().getUniversalID());
print(docData.getItemValueString("Subject"));}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("beforeRenderResponse");
print(docData.getDocument().getUniversalID());
print(docData.getItemValueString("Subject"));}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>

</xp:view>
```

**Output:**[image]

It seems, that now the data source isn't available anymore in the `beforerenderrepsone` event?

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of potential aspects at work here. I identified something about datasource computation settings time ago and covered in sessions at Connect, Engage and delivered in the "Marty, You're Just Not Thinking Fourth Dimensionally" TLCC webinar (look at the last one of 2016 [here](http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/recorded-xpages-webinars)). If a datasource is attached to an XPage, it gets loaded during the `createView` method of the ViewHandler, which runs before `beforePageLoad`. If it's attached to a component on the XPage (Panel, Custom Control etc), it gets calculated when that component's properties get calculated, during `beforePageLoad`. See slide 10 on the slides.

Another element worth bearing in mind is you're setting `documentId` property, but not setting `ignoreRequestParams`. So what's likely to be happening (again, it's worth watching that webinar) is that in `beforePageLoad` you're getting the document you are specifying, but in `beforeRenderResponse` the datasource is being told to look at the request parameters, which are blank, so a *new* document is being created. Obviously you can't get the backend Document for a new document - because it's not been saved yet, so doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure that slide 10 of  "Marty, You're Just Not Thinking Fourth Dimensionally" presentation is the right one?

Comment: Sorry, I was working from  my original slide deck for Connect. On that slide deck it's 18.